# Using boost geometry with geographic coordinates

Tags: c++, boost, geometry

I'm looking for tips on how to use boost::geometry with geographic coordinates.
When I try to use any algorithm (area,sym_difference, etc.) I get the assertion `not implemented for this type`.
I should probably use the strategy version, but I can't find information on how to use it.
In addition to the strategies (whose names don't tell me much) there are also formulas (these don't tell me much either) that I don't even know and where to use.
For example, I have no idea whats the difference between:
`boost::geometry::strategies::area::geographic<...>` and `boost::geometry::strategy::area::geographic<...>`.

Can anyone recommend some good sources for using boost::geometry with geographic coords?

Definitions:

```
namespace bg = boost::geometry;
`using point_t = bg::model::point<double,2,bg::cs::geographics<bg::degree>>;
using polygon_t = bg::model::polygon<point_t>;
```

How to do `sym_difference` for two `polygon_t`?

Comment: There have been some decent conference talks on Boost Geometry by active developers (Barend Gehrels and Adam Wulkiewicz if memory serves). That's about the best I can do. There's some quality content in the mailing list, but sadly that can be a bit noisy :)

Comment: Thanks. I'll definitely take a look!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah Boost Geometry doesn't contain a lot of useful examples in the documentation.

I tend to browse the tests and examples. E.g. `test/algorithms/equals/equals_on_spheroid.cpp` and `exmple/with_external_libs/x02_gd_example.cpp` perhaps show relevant stuff.

As far as the algorithm invocation, nothing much changes with the coordinate systems, so here's a simple example ([kml](http://stackoverflow-sehe.s3.amazonaws.com/00dda02d-0c56-4d67-b800-7e97256c2960/test.kml))

[image]

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7fbe2e5a04fa7a75)**

```
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/polygon.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/multi_polygon.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

namespace bg = boost::geometry;

int main()
{
    using point_t     = bg::model::point<double, 2, bg::cs::geographic<bg::degree>>;
    using polygon_t   = bg::model::polygon<point_t>;
    using multipoly_t = bg::model::multi_polygon<polygon_t>;

    polygon_t yellow, red;
    bg::read_wkt("POLYGON(("
                 "-3.961914389187368 11.28891625894777,"
                 "-3.133187356915983 13.75456077295048,"
                 "2.138821161614763 12.20096628831674,"
                 "-0.8928914314224368 11.0376804788117,"
                 "-3.961914389187368 11.28891625894777))",
                 yellow);

    bg::read_wkt("POLYGON(("
                 "-3.123808144039304 11.56617971394363,"
                 "-3.100483965667017 12.65141090156214,"
                 "-0.7589096547593077 12.71523653133145,"
                 "-0.4741675169773574 11.59870292442133,"
                 "-3.123808144039304 11.56617971394363"
                 "))",
                 red);

    for (auto& shape : {yellow, red}) {
        if (std::string r; !bg::is_valid(shape, r)) {
            std::cout << r << std::endl;
            return 255;
        }
    }

    multipoly_t result;
    bg::sym_difference(yellow, red, result);

    std::cout << "yellow:     " << bg::wkt(yellow) << "\n";
    std::cout << "red:        " << bg::wkt(red)    << "\n";
    std::cout << "difference: " << bg::wkt(result) << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
yellow:     POLYGON((-3.96191 11.2889,-3.13319 13.7546,2.13882 12.201,-0.892891 11.0377,-3.96191 11.2889))
red:        POLYGON((-3.12381 11.5662,-3.10048 12.6514,-0.75891 12.7152,-0.474168 11.5987,-3.12381 11.5662))
difference: MULTIPOLYGON(((-3.96191 11.2889,-3.13319 13.7546,2.13882 12.201,-0.892891 11.0377,-3.96191 11.2889),(-3
.12381 11.5662,-0.474168 11.5987,-0.75891 12.7152,-3.10048 12.6514,-3.12381 11.5662)))
```

> *Disclaimer: I'm not into GIS or geodesy so I might have made a mess of
> the projection. I did work out that the long/lat order was what seems
> to be expected, although the example mentioned above uses a *specific*
> latlong order.*

Comment: Thanks. Looks like I messed up with the headers as the code started to compile after rewrite.